# "returned as a different man" or " returned a different man"?

Tags: syntax, adjuncts

> If he had fought in the First World War, he might have returned _____.

Is it correct to insert " as a different man" or " a different man"?

I suppose both are correct.  "as a different man" function as an adverb phrase for return; for "a different man," I think it is an adjunct for "he," to give more description of him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK we say, "returned a different man". We might also say "a [changed man](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/changed-man)."

If we were to say, "He returned **as** a different man" it would mean he was *pretending* to be a different man, one of the meanings of **as** being "*in the rôle of* " or "*playing the part of.*" For example, if an actor plays two parts in a film we might we say he "returns *as* a different man."

As you say, without "as" it is an adjunct; *with* "as" it's an adverbial phrase.